Failing unit tests result in obscure error message on CI build / pull request when using DotNetCoreCLI
I've got our CI pipeline set up to run tests, but when a test fails, rather than getting a meaningful error like "2 unit tests failed", we get the following:

Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]

(It's worth nothing that the "projects" list is apparently empty in the second error when auto-detecting the solution file. If I explicitly specify the solution or projects path, it appears in the error)

Devs would have to go poring through the job console logs to see that actually they just broke a unit test, rather than it being something wrong with the DevOps infrastructure or CI pipeline setup (which is their assumption):

Here's how the solution is building and running tests:
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Projects'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore'
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-build --no-restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish Deployable Projects'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    etc...

Is something lacking in this setup, or is the DotNetCoreCLI@2 "test" command just not mature in this regard?
I've used other pipelines using vstest / mstest commands directly and had nicer output, but I was hoping I could do everything with DotNetCoreCLI@2 for a variety of reasons, such as being able to chain several steps together without having to re-build the solution.

I just found this similar issue from 3 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68043052/how-to-surface-unit-test-failure-messages-as-build-errors-in-net-core - which linked to a github issue that is closed as completed. Perhaps the fixes haven't rolled out the command has to be run in a certain way to benefit from it. (By any chance is @nohwnd still kicking around SO?)

As a workaround, I've added a new pipeline step which runs only if the tests failed, and adds a new error output.
For whatever reason, pull request check failures only relay the error messages of the most recently failed task, so by adding a task which adds a new failure message, it "hides" the 2 obscure error messages, and replaces them with a more meaningful one:

Upon clicking the error (which navigates to the failed build) - we will still see the two obscure error messages, but also now the third one which the developers can hopefully focus on:

Here's the additions to the pipeline which take care of this:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Mark Build as Succeeded'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task.build_suceeded]true"'
  condition: succeeded()

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '--no-build --no-restore --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code Coverage"'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Automated Tests Failed'
  condition: and (failed(), eq(variables['task.build_suceeded'], 'true'))
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]The build succeeded, but one or more tests failed. Check the `"Tests`" tab for details on failed tests."'


I went the extra mile here of setting a variable first to indicate that all prior steps succeeded (e.g. the restore / build steps) so that we only show this new error message when test test job fails, but everything else succeeds. If the build itself fails, this message won't show up.

I can reproduce the issue when using DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to run tests and there are failed tests.

According to dotnet test,

If all tests are successful, the test runner returns 0 as an exit code; otherwise if any test fails, it returns 1.

It's an expected behavior of Dotnet test command. But when dotnet test command returns a non-zero exit code, the Pipeline will read the exit code as an error and fail the task.
There are two workarounds for your reference.
Workaround1: use PowerShell task to run the dotnet test and ignore this expected exit code.
In PowerShell task, you can set the ignoreLASTEXITCODE to true to ignore the non-zero exit code.
Add --logger trx --results-directory $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) to your dotnet test command to create a test result file and publish it to the pipeline using a PublishTestResults@2 task.
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet test {Your proj} --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-build --no-restore --logger trx --results-directory $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    ignoreLASTEXITCODE: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'

Result:


Workaround2: Add continueOnError: true to your dotnet test task.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-build --no-restore'

This will allow subsequent tasks to ignore the status of this task and continue running. The build will be in a partially successful state.

Note: If your dotnet test fails for other reasons, subsequent tasks can still run.

Thank you for the proposed workaround. It will probably work for many folks. In my case I want the build to fail (I don't want devs merging pull requests with failing tests) - but I want the failure message to be more clear (like what is seen in the first picture here: https://www.codewrecks.com/post/azdo/pipeline/reruntest/ )

I am afraid DotNetCoreCLI@2 can't provide such error currently. Thanks for sharing your great workaround.
